# How to check if a node contains relation with other node with 2 specific codes in it but not a particular code in Neo4j Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried as below

```
Match(A)-[r1]->(B) where B.Code IN ['aaa', 'bbb'] and B.Code <> 'ccc' 
return A, B
```

seems to be incorrect. This returns  records of B with 'aaa' and 'bbb' ignoring 'ccc'.
I dont want to return B at all if it has 'ccc'. Not just ignore that relation.

**Other tries: same result as above**

```
Match(A)->[r1]->(B) where B.Code <> 'ccc'
With *
Match(A)->[r1]->(B) where B.Code IN ['aaa', 'bbb']
return A, B
```

[image]

Its is returning me A with aaa, A with bbb and X with aaa and X with bbb. I am expecting only X. Could you please correct where I am doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
MATCH (A)-->(B)
WHERE B.Code IN ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
WITH A, COLLECT(B) AS bs, COLLECT(B.Code) AS codes
WHERE 'ccc' NOT IN codes
RETURN A, bs
```